# Distribution adhoc profile denies access to contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My distribution profile does not allow me to access contacts of my iPhone, Do I need to get some special permission from apple? My developer profile works well i.e it can access the contacts of my phone whereas distribution profile denies it. And it is working well in simulator also both in ios 5 simulator as well as iOS 6 simulator.

thanks in advance..

```
__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)          {
    NSLog(@"Error ref %@",error);
    NSLog(@"Access %i",accessGranted);
    accessGranted = granted;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
});
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(sema);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
//my code
}
```

Comment: I dont think there is some connection between both.Hey all other operations work in your application?

Comment: yes lithu all other things are perfectly working, Only my device contacts are not getting accessed

Comment: please include the code for contacts in the question

Comment: ok lithu, I have added

Comment: Try deleting and reinstalling the app once

Comment: I have done that too for so many times... but no use, only for that particular profile its not working

Comment: Did you sort this out?  If so, what was the resolution?